# Tor and IPv6 exit nodes

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, ipv6

I use Windows and created my own program in which I use tor.exe. Only I need an exit node with IPv6. How do I configure torrc for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en), you can set:

> **PreferIPv6**
>
> Tells exits that, if a host has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address, we
>   would prefer to connect to it via IPv6. (IPv4 is the default.)

There is also:

> **IPv6Only**
>
> If the address is absent, or resolves to both an IPv4 and an IPv6
>   address, only listen to the IPv6 address.

This second one is a little vague, so I have no idea if it will do anything.